# Using Viber API without public account

Tags: viber

According to Viber site's documentation, a public account (PA) is required to work with its API: https://developers.viber.com/api/rest-bot-api/index.html. There is a standard form for registering these accounts by providing company's information, can be found at https://www.viber.com/en/public-accounts. But I'm just a developer who wants to try out the API using my own Viber account.

Can I achieve this without the creation of a PA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Unfortunately its not possible to send bot messages to private account without public account. Its not possible to assign bot to your private account. Public account is in a way account for you bot. Viber needs to know who is sending message and to whom (PA account = bot).

Easiest way would be creating public account but not publishing it so that it doesn't appear in search result. While PA is not published you can add other developers / testers by adding participants using their mobile number and then granting them admin rights if needed.

Comment: > Easiest way would be creating public account but not publishing it so that it doesn't appear in search result.

Comment: Well that way you can send message to users that joined your account but you avoid having public account publicly listed. I believe this is the closest to you desired behavior.

Comment: Sorry, posted the previous comment unfinished. _Easiest way would be creating public account but not publishing it so that it doesn't appear in search result._ Do you mean that it is possible to create a public account without submitting an online form? It seems to me there was such kind of a functionality during the beta test (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-own-public-chats-in-viber) but seems now this feature is not available. At least I was not able to find this button on my cell phone with the recent version of Viber.

Comment: I am not 100% sure since it did change recently but i believe you have to fill in online form only when creating your first PA. Once you have PA you can create new PAs from inside Viber app. As far as i understood web form serves as application for early access to PA feature.